# java.lang.Long is matching java.lang.String

Tags: java, scala

I need to find out if a class type is String in Scala.

```
val classType = schema.field.type
classType match {
  case _: Class[String] => println("String")
  case _: Class[_] => println("Others")
```

But even when the `classType` is `java.lang.Long` it prints `String`. I have two questions :

1. Why is this happening?
2. What are the other ways to do the same?

Comment: Yes, I did , but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching on erased type. This code should produce a compile time warning that the type parameter is not checked.
Note that in the JVM we have for better or worse type erasure. The type parameters exist in compile time but are gone in runtime.

If what you have is class instances you probably want to check equality of the instances rather than the type of the class.

you can try something else:

```
val STR_CLASS=classOf[String]
val LONG_CLASS=classOf[Long]

classType match {
  case STR_CLASS => println("String")
  case LONG_CLASS => println("Long")
}
```

Note the uppercase variable names are important.